# How to treat all audio as "one shot" in Acid Pro 7 and disable tempo

Tags: sync, importing

I'm using Acid pro to mix down my radio show and it's driving me mad because it tends to import all samples as "loop" or "Beatmapped" and I have to change them manually.

I'd also like to disable the feature that synchronizes the looped track to the tempo of the track, is this possible?  I have two tracks that I use when I'm talking and they are short loops that must mantain their original tempo.

Comment: This response will not answer your question but I will state that I've used Acid for 10 years now and I compose songs with up to 70 tracks of instrument samples at a time. (That includes, guitars, vocals, drum sounds, fx, blahblahblah) and the manual de-looping process kills. I haven't found a single answer anywhere as to how to turn that ---- off cause I hate it. Why can't you just highlight all the tracks and select one-shot? Can't there be a checkbox in preferences for auto-looping? Idk.

Comment: It seems impossible to fix that out. I also need to make them loops as one-shot but i can't find it. If you guys know the fixing please feedback.

Comment: @Dilshod actually the answer, which i have now accepted, more or less works. YOu must tell Acid to open files as loop only if they are 2 seconds long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options -> Preferences -> Audio

1) *Open files as loop if*... X seconds

Set it to something silly

2) *Acid type for recorded audio:*
Choose One-shot instead of Beatmapped

Comment: When you say "Set it to something silly" do you mean a rather large or small value, or a random value?